# New row added can't be edited

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am using codeigniter and bootstrap-editable.js,etc as plugin. I made an editable table with empty values. I just displayed one row and made an addrow button if the user wants to add new row. The addnew button has a mouseclick event, it will automatically add an empty new row. I want that new added row to be editable also.. But as in my case/code, it didn't work..

Here's my code:

```
<table class="table " id="memberTB">
    <thead><tr><th >First Name</th><th >Middle Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
                   <tr><td><span class="edit"></span></td>
                   <td><span class="edit"></span></td>
                   <td><span class="edit"></span></td></tr>
    </tbody>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="addrow"><span class="fa fa-plus"> Add new row</span></button>

</table>
```

Here's the Javascript code:

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
$.fn.editable.defaults.showbuttons = false;
$.fn.editable.defaults.url = '/post';
$.fn.editable.defaults.type = 'text';

// make all items having class 'edit' editable
$('.edit').editable();


//ajax emulation
$.mockjax({
url: '/post',
responseTime: 200,
response: function(settings) {
    console.log('done!');
    }
}); 

// this is to automatically make the next item in the table editable
$('.edit').on('save', function(e, params){
var that = this;
// persist the old value in the element to be restored when clicking reset
var oldItemValue = $(that)[0].innerHTML;
if (!$(that).attr('oldValue')) {
    console.log('persisting original value: ' + oldItemValue)
    $(that).attr('oldValue', oldItemValue);
}
setTimeout(function() {
    // first search the row
    var item = $(that).closest('td').next().find('.edit');
    console.log(item);
    if (item.length == 0) {
        // check the next row
        item = $(that).closest('tr').next().find('.edit');
    }
    item.editable('show');
    }, 200);
});
$('#addrow').click(function() {
$('#memberTB > tbody:last').append(' <tr><td><span class="edit"></span></td><td><span class="edit"></span></td><td><span class="edit"></span></td></tr>');
});
```

How can I make the new added row to be editable? Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `$('#addrow').click(function() {});`, I would add this:

```
$('.edit').off();
$('.edit').fn1();
$('.edit').fn2();
```

With `fn1` and `fn2` being whatever functions are bound to the `edit` class already (i.e. .editable and .on)

That rebinds the function to the selected elements, but first removes the binding so elements don't get double (or triple, etc.) bindings.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.. It worked..I changed the functions `fn1,fn2` and `off` to `editable`..